# Selenium - Not able to select option from drop down

Tags: select, selenium, drop-down-menu

Following is the code:

```
public static void test1() {  
System.out.print("\nTo find UserName element");
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("drop_down")));
System.out.print("\nElements found");
select.selectByIndex(1);
}
```

Neither following wroks:

```
select.selectByIndex(1);
select.selectByValue("1");
select.selectByVisibleText("Super Admin");
```

It throws an exception:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate option with value: 1

```
<select id="drop_down" style="width:205px;" name="drop_down">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">
        Super Admin
    </option>
    <option value="4">
        Question Reviewer
    </option>
    <option value="6">
    Evaluator
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: The value of drop down is populated based on email entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**May be the dropdown is not properly loaded, when you try to access it**.

Try the below code to **wait till the number of options in the dropdown becomes greater than 1, and then select the first option from it**:

```
try{
    // Waits for 20 seconds
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

    // Wait until expected condition size of the dropdown increases and becomes more than 1
    wait.until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>(){
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver)  
        {
            Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("drop_down")));
            return select.getOptions().size()>1;
        }
    });

    //To select the first option
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("drop_down")));
    select.selectByVisibleText("Super Admin");
}catch(Throwable e){
    System.out.println("Error found: "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Still receiving same error as:
 Cannot locate element with text: Super Admin

Comment: I have to select Super Admin.

Comment: Okay.. Can you please add the **HTML snippet of the dropdown, before the email address is entered**, as you said **"The value of drop down is populated based on email entered"**? I will modify my code accordingly then,

Comment: <select id="drop_down" style="width:205px;" name="drop_down">

    <option value="">

        Select Role

    </option>

</select>

Comment: Also, name in above snippet of html is like drop_down[index]

Comment: Does the option **"Select Role"** vanish after the email address is entered ? Also, what did you mean, when you said **name in above snippet of html is like drop_down[index]** ? Please explain..

Comment: No, select role does nto vanish. Only the drop down list is pouplated as per value entered in email field. 
The name of drop down is "drop_down[index]".

Comment: After you enter the email address, does the page refreshes, or any ajax loader appears, after which the dropdown gets updated ?

Comment: Page do not get refreshed, ajax is used to load values.

Comment: I have edited my code above.. See if it works out for you and let me know too, please..

Answer (score 1):

Hi as per the first comment bu Subh on Jan 15 at 6:35 I too modified the code but getting the same error as mentioned by Abhinav on Jan 15 at 6:53 after that Subh said "I have edited my code above.. See if it works out for you and let me know too, please.." but I didn't see any modified code after this comment hence this didn't help....finally I searched few other forums and I tried using `selectByIndex()` as:-

```
WebElement toactTyp=driver1.findElement(By.name((<Name of the Element to access>)));
Select toactSel=new Select(toactTyp);
toactSel.selectByIndex(2);
```

It worked well with the above code.....I request to please share the modified code or atleast the lines where the modification has been done as it useful to a lot like me

Comment: Almost 2 years later. Sorry for the late response.. :)
Actually I did modify the code. Earlier it was just waiting for the dropdown to appear and then selecting the relevant option. After OP replied back, it was confirmed that the app was using ajax to load options as the email address entered. Hence, I modified the code to wait till the options count>1, and then `selectByVisibleText`, wherein I could've used `selectByindex` and given '1' which would've worked as well. For normal purpose your code is what is expected, of course since yours is the case where the dropdown options are constant.