# Not able to select Drop Down values in Selenium Webdriver with Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How can I select an item from a drop down list in below code:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mob-spacing-bx">
<label>Type of Transaction</label>

<select id="tType" class="new_case_input_margin bs-select-hidden" value="" onchange="ShowHideMortageFields()"   name="CaseDetailsModel.TransactionType" enableaddnew="true">
<option class="bs-title-option" value="">Select Type</option>
<option value="Purchase">Purchase</option>
<option value="Sale">Sale</option>
<option value="Re-Mortgage">Re-Mortgage</option>
</select>

<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select new_case_input_margin">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" data-id="tType"   title="Select   Type" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="filter-option pull-left">Select Type</span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>

<div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 91px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 0px;">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu" style="max-height: 79px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px;">
    <li data-original-index="1">
        <a class="" data-tokens="null" style="" tabindex="0">
            <span class="text">Purchase</span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li data-original-index="2">
        <a class="" data-tokens="null" style="" tabindex="0">
        <span class="text">Sale</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li data-original-index="3">
        <a class="" data-tokens="null" style="" tabindex="0">
        <span class="text">Re-Mortgage</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    </ul>

</div>

</div>
<span class="required">*</span>
<input id="status" type="hidden" value="" name="CaseDetailsModel.Status_DONT">
```

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to answer at below link:
[Selenium - Not able to select option from drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957851/selenium-not-able-to-select-option-from-drop-down)

It contains code on selecting from down.

PS: You should write the code which you have tried to have a better idea of problem being faced